# GCC -D equivalent for iarbuild.exe

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, iar

I have a build machine server I am maintaining which is using Makefiles infrastructure.

As part of that infrastructure, I'm passing a few arguments to the Makefile from the build machine (example: user, build-server name, and various build variables known only when compiling for a specific project).

Some of these variables are aggregated to the code using gcc -D directive

```
-DSOME_VAR=VAL
```

I've now been asked to migrate an Iar Project into my build system. That is not a problem in itself, only I can't find any way to introduce preprocessor defines using iarbuild.exe command line tool.

I guess I could use an existing H file and edit it before compiling (using sed for example), but that's an ugly hack I would rather avoid if I can.

How do I properly achieve this with IAR?

Comment: run IarBuild.exe without parameters to get Usage information. This might show what option you need.

Comment: Thanks. Of course I did that, and also consulted with the relevant IAR manuals. Very little is written about the command line tool and I didn't find even the smallest hint that such a feature is supported by iarbuild.exe. I decided to ask and see if maybe I missed something before I go and implement a very ugly hack...

Comment: Well, I guess there really isn't a way to do it. I'll just go with the ugly hack. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding iarbuild does not support passing such parameters directly.

There are two possibilities that were suggested by IAR support and that both work for me (using 7.40.2):

1) Use a preinclude file

- Go to Project->Options->C/C++ Compiler->Preprocessor
- Add a preinclude file (e.g. preinclude.h)
- Now have your build script generate that preinclude file before starting iarbuild

2) Use "Defined symbols"

- Go to Project->Options->C/C++ Compiler->Preprocessor
- Add an option to "Defined symbols" and use environment variable, e.g. `"SOMEVAR=$_SOMEVAL_$"`
- On the cmd line, set the environment variable, e.g. "set SOMEVAR=myvalue"
- Run iarbuild

The 2nd method is little more elegant, but the build will fail if the environment variable is not set, so I'll probably go with the 1st method.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it long ago, same way as your 1st option. It's also what I said in the question, that I could use an existing H file (or create a new one, whatever works) but I wanted to see if there was a more standard solution to this. I accepted your answer since it's the way I eventually used to solve the problem. Works pretty well, although took some time to properly and generically implement, instead of a simple -D directive. :(

Comment: Yes, it's sad that IAR does not support a better way of doing this. The nice thing about using the "predefine" header file is that you don't have to include it in your code, but iarbuild includes it automatically if specified so in the project options.

Comment: Yes, but I guess IAR will fail if that file doesn't exist. The build server is a convenient and efficient tool to creating official release of the software, but I want to preserve compilation without it (via command line or in IAR). That's why I personally preferred using an existing file, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 4):

I recently solved this using a combination of option #2 and the -varfile argvarfile option to iarbuild.exe. For my case I am controlling the output of cpputest. I need easy to read outputs for IDE builds but junit formatted outputs for build server builds. Here's my setup as an example.

1. Create a global variable in the IDE. Tools->Configure Custom Argument Variables...
   Select global tab. Create group JUNIT. Create variable USE_JUNIT. Set the value to 0.
2. In the Project->Options->C/C++ Compiler->Preprocessor section add an entry for

   ```
   JUNIT_OUTPUT=$USE_JUNIT$
   ```
3. In the code use

   ```
   #if JUNIT_OUTPUT == 1
       #define FLAGS "-ojunit"
   #else
       #define FLAGS "-v"
   #endif
   ```
4. Create a file called jUnitOut.txt and put the following into it.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

   <iarUserArgVars>
     <group active="true" name="JUNIT">
       <variable>
         <name>USE_JUNIT</name>
         <value>1</value>
       </variable>
     </group>
   </iarUserArgVars>
   ```
5. Call iarbuild.exe with the normal options plus -varfile jUnitOut.txt

Some observations

Regarding #1 you don't actually need to create a global variable but when you do IAR creates ...\AppData\Roaming\IAR Embedded Workbench\global.custom_argvars. This file must be present for iarbuild.exe to use the -varfile you provide. Also, you can create workspace variables as well. These are stored in a file in the local project directory. This file can be added to source control so global variables can be avoided. IDE builds use the global and workspace variables while iarbuild will use the -varfile

Regarding #4 I didn't find any documentation on how to format the argvarfile. So, I created a workspace variable in the IDE, found the file it created to store the variable and then cut/pasted from that file into my jUnitOut.txt

Comment: Thanks so much for reverse engineering the varfile format. Losing my mind over the lack of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This may answer your question:

To see the command line parameters, enable the option IAR Embedded Workbench IDE > Tools > Options... > IDE Options > Messages > Show build messages > select 'All'.

which is part of the web page at:
http://supp.iar.com/Support/?Note=47884

Comment: Thank you. Indeed it shows iccarm compilation directive which is similar to GCC, but using that (as I understand) would require me to maintain my own build environment in addition to that of the ewp file already maintained by the relevant team. That's not something I can afford to do. That's why I'm opting to use iarbuild tool in the first place.